# Android : Close Activity after Result

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, locationlistener

I've written a Small Google Maps Application, which makes me a few Problems.

The LocationListener i wrote, overrides the onProviderDisabled Method to call an Activity, where the User can Switch on his GPS.

This do the Job well, but one Problem is still there. If i close the Maps_Activity and after that shut down the GPS, it seems, that the Listener is already running, because the Activity (the one who says me, that the GPS is not running) still pops up.

The LocationListner as followed:

```js
public class LocationUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMapView.getController().animateTo(
                        mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NoGpsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS ready", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The NoGPSAcivity.class as followed:

```
public class NoGpsActivity extends Activity {

private OnClickListener mEnableGPSListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps_not_available_overlay);

        Button mEnableGPS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablegps_button);

        mEnableGPS.setOnClickListener(mEnableGPSListener);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 0){
        finish();
    }
}



 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) method you need to call [removeUpdates(locationListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) so it will stop receiving updates.

Also another thing to watch out for is that the "Home" key in Android generally means "minimize" (leaving your program in the background) while the "Back" key means "close". So if your hitting home to exit, most likely it is still running.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks alot, your solution works fine for me. I put the removeUpdates(LocationListener) into the onDestroy-Method of my MapView. Thanks!